# JQuery standalone Value Slider (not the image one)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I'm looking for a small standalone analog of JQuery UI slider (the one which a draggable thumb), could anyone recommend one?

Eventually I'm planning to create my own slider, so using JQuery UI would be a total overkill for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery UI wouldn't be an overkill for you. If you want only the slider component, it will be around 20 kb. You are probably looking for http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: Sorry, but how do I get just the slider - does it have a small standalone script?

Comment: Did you read my question? What you gave me is a link to a part of JQuery UI (which we both agreed to be an overkill). How odd is that? Could you edit your answer and I'll minus it?

Comment: I think you misread my answer. I said it would not be an overkill. Head over to the jQuery UI page. There you can select only what components you require. 20 kb should be just fine.

Comment: yes, that's right I found that. size is not the only problme though, I'm planning to acquire the full ownership for the control at some stage. nevermind thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use html5, then use the input type="range" element. see http://olav.dk/wf2/demo/range.asp

Comment: Got it now, it doesn't work with FF, but works with Chromium, which is a bit of a stiff for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/ - very easy to integrate.

Other plugins listed here: http://www.unheap.com/section/inputs-forms/input-sliders/